# Token authorization for an android app

Tags: android, authorization, android-service, basic-authentication, android-internet

I am trying to use secure web API from my Android app. The web API uses basic authentication and a the use of a server generated token. I have been able to use the web API using curl as shown below.

Firstly, to authenticate the user and get the token.

`curl http://localhost:3000/api/api_keys -u 'user@example.com:UserPassword'`

returns `{"token":"0d63b512573dce7be5eb53bab58a5625"}`

Secondly, I use the token to call the API as an authenticated user.

`curl http://localhost:3000/api/exams -H 'Authorization: Token token="0d63b512573dce7be5eb53bab58a5625"'`

return the appropriate json object.

The problem is when I try to call the web API from the Android client using the code below, the web API doesn't pick up the Authorization header and so throws the request out.

```
...
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(targetUrl.toString());
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test-user@example.com", "Password!"), "UTF-8", false));
httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"" + getToken() + "\"");

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
...
```

How should I authenticate the Android app to the web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I was sending the user credentials again when making the 'authenticated' request. This was causing the server to ignore the token and return a 401 unauthorised response.

So the fix was to the remove the following line from my 'authenticated request'.

`httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test-user@example.com", "Password!"), "UTF-8", false));`

To be clear, this line is still necessary for the first request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send request first to get the token. Then, you can use the token.